# Check if file descriptor is valid

Tags: python, python-2.6, file-descriptor

How do I check to see if a given file descriptor is valid? I want to write to `fd=3` if it's available; otherwise, I want to write to stdout. I'm aware that I could wrap every `os.write` call with try-except statement, but I would like to know ahead of time if `fd=3` is writable or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`os.fstat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fstat) to determine if the file descriptor is valid before each write, but you will need to wrap it in a try/except anyway because invalid file descriptors will raise an `OSError`.  You are probably better off just creating your own write function with a try/except.

```
def write(data, fd=3):
    try:
        os.write(fd, data)
    except OSError:
        sys.stdout.write(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about trying to `os.write` to `fd=3` once at the start (inside a `try`-`except` block), and change all subsequent behaviour based on the success of that?

This way you won't have to wrap every call in `try`-`except`. Of course, this will break down if `fd=3` stops being valid in the middle of your problem (e.g. if it's a pipe that gets closed from the other end).

Comment: I'd try calling `os.fstat` and check the mode bits rather than `os.write`, to avoid the side effect of writing junk to the fd, but otherwise yeah, try/except is the perfect idiom for this problem. "better to ask for forgiveness etc"

Comment: @Chris Farmiloe: Would `os.fstat` detect a broken pipe?

Comment: Yeah will raise an "Operation on closed file" `ValueError` I believe